# Eclipse: Glassfish and Tomcat don't work

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, glassfish

I have reinstalled java JDK 6.0.25,(after some problems installing java, finally succeeded). I have set paths (JAVA_HOME points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25 and in Path also added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin).

In eclipse I have pointed everything to this new JDK, also in servers. When I have installed Glassfish 3.1, after installation the domain wasn't created. So when I add this server in Eclipse, the domain wasn't found.

So I did extract an ZIP version of Glassfish and in Eclipse configure the server to this ZIPPED Glassfish. Also I have installed tomcat 7.0.14 again and add to eclipse but both did not work.

**Main problem:** When I start Tomcat or Glassfish in Eclipse they don't start. Tomcat is starting but after 45 seconds it says, that the time is run out. I have read the forums to increase starting time, I have putted it to 240 sec, but it does not work, because it pop out error in which sazs, that the port is already used by a different server.

By Glassfish, when I start it, its starting, but after few minutes gives me error: Failed to start. It looks like some ports or something is blocking this servers. I have turned off firewall also and antivirus but nothing.

I have looked all the forum about "not starting Glassfish or Tomcat" but didn't found the solution. I don't want to reinstall windows for this.
So if anyone know anything about this problem, please HELP.

#### Update:

I've tried to change the ports in domain.xml and checked with netstat -b (everything was established), but the server (Glassfish) didn't start. It shows an error "Server GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3 (Java EE 6) at localhost failed to start.". I've also tried install "built in Eclipse" Glassfish from marketspace and from "Install new software" from eclipse, but it comes out with the same error. Currently, for needs I'm using XP Mode in Windows 7, there servers work, without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your installation odyssey messed up your system.

But you should get it working without reinstalling Windows. Maybe the fragment of an old server installation blocks the ports Glassfish and Tomcat need for operation.

Try the following:

1. Check which ports your "new" servers try to access (should be something like 8080 and should be written in server logs during startup)
2. Use `netstat -b` (from cmd started with admin rights) to check which application blocks this / these ports (could be java.exe if there is an old installation still hanging)
3. Remove the old installation (uninstall or disable service)
4. Try again to start your new server(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try tell to GF or TC to bind the default web listener other port than 8080, because this is a root of problem.
I doesn't know well TC, but in GF case, this is very easy. Simply edit $GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml and find something similar:

```
   <network-listener port="8080" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
```

And replace 8080 with other port (but not same with TC). In your case I could choose 8888 which is easy to remember but you can pretty sure this is differs from TC's port.

Note: Edit this file **before** you start GF!